# Hardcoding a specific server into Speedtest.net or Fast.com links

Tags: speedtest

We have to measure speed on a number of similar devices, connected to various ISPs. It would be fair to test the speed against the same server, but choosing it manually each time before starting the test is time-consuming. Is there a way to hotlink to a specific server predefined? Something like `speedtest.net/paris-1`.

I know I can set a predefined server on my account, but there's too many devices to have to log on on each of them.